# The nginx only load the index.php

Tags: php, nginx, lxc, nginx-location

I have a problem with my nginx configuration. We have a Vagrant box at the firm. In this vagrant we have LXC containers for services like nginx container, php-fpm container, memcached container, mysql container... These are connecting to each other, nginx use php-fpm, php-fpm use memcached and mysql. I have access to the nginx outside the vagrant through https. Here is my nginx configuration:

```
nginx.conf:

user              nginx  nginx;

worker_processes  4;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

worker_rlimit_nofile 1024;

events {
        worker_connections 2048;
        use epoll;
        multi_accept on;
}


http {

       include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        access_log "/var/log/nginx/access.log";
        error_log "/var/log/nginx/error.log";
        keepalive_timeout 120;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
deault.conf:

server {
   listen *:80;
   server_name vagrant.ceg.com;
   return 301 'https://$server_name$request_uri';
}

https.conf:

server {
   listen *:443;
   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate ....crt;
   ssl_certificate_key ....key;
   server_name vagrant.ceg.com www.vagrant.ceg.com;
   root "/srv/www";
   index index.php;
   location / {
       autoindex on;

   }
   location ~ \.php$ {
       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param ENVIRONMENT dev;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       if (-f $request_filename) {
       fastcgi_pass 192.168.42.114:9000;
   }

   }
}
```

When I open it in the browser I get the index.php, but very slowly, and I got same errors on the console like this:

```
https://www.vagrant.ceg.com/cdn/util/scale/320/320/dev-employer-images/0636443e3076af9d24ba2b1711f57fb47b60f289.jpg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Comment: How do you setup your SSL Certificate (with `vagrant.ceg.com www.vagrant.ceg.com`)?

Comment: Nope, wildcard.ceg.com, is there the problem?

Comment: `*.ceg.com` can only match `vagrant.ceg.com` not `www.vagrant.ceg.com`.

Comment: If I have saved wildcard.ceg.com.key and wildcard.ceg.com.crt how can I add these that it is work for www too? Srry I never do that, and I dont know.

Comment: I think you should try `ServerAliasNames`(here is a blog on linode https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/multiple-ssl-sites-using-subjectaltname) or generate different certificate for these two domains.